# Search for a list item attribute with another attribute value of the item

Tags: c#, linq, list, object

I have a class like this:

```
class item   
{
    public string itemID { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public decimal itemPrice{ get; set; }
}
```

I have a lists like this:

```
List<item> myItems = new List<item>();
```

I want to get the id of the item with minimum price.

I get the minimum price like this:

```
var minprice = myItems.Min(itemobj => itemobj.itemPrice);
```

How can I get the Item ID of the object which is having minprice? Or in other words itemID of the object which is:

```
itemPrice == minprice;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

Try to get the whole item

```
var minPriceItem = myItems.OrderBy(i => i.itemPrice).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then just use it's properties:

```
decimal price = minPriceItem.itemPrice;

string id = minPriceItem.itemID;
```

Comment: When you will search the cheapest car in the car showroom, are you going to rearrange them all to have the cheapest next to door?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do it like this:

```
var minprice = myItems.Min(itemobj => itemobj.itemPrice);
// use .First instead of .Single in case there are 2 or more items with the same min price
// use .FirstOrDefault instead of .First in case the sequence is empty
var itemWithMinPrice = myItems.FirstOrDefault(itemobj => itemobj.itemPrice == minprice);
```

If you want all the items with the minimum price:

```
var itemsWithMinPrice = myItems.Where(itemobj => itemobj.itemPrice == minprice);
```

You can also go advanced with the aggregate function

```
var itemWithMinPrice = myItems.Aggregate((cheapestItem, nextItem) => (cheapestItem == null || cheapestItem.itemPrice > nextItem.itemPrice) ? nextItem : cheapestItem);
```

Or you can use [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) (I can recommend this, MoreLinq is fantastic)

```
var itemWithMinPrice = myItems.MinBy(itemobj => itemobj.Price);
```

Comment: I prefer two linear operations (min and search) than sorting whole list just to get one item.

Comment: Two linear operations are less efficient than sorting with `n log(n)` complexity?

Comment: @GrantWinney, I'm not a fan of micro-optimizations but "performance-aware thinking" is a good habit I believe. What if there will be millions of items in this list?